# SQL: Insert from first table into second table when records not exist in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two table with same column but the second table has a column more than first table(`InfoDate`).

**Table 1**

```
KID       ParentID         KLevel
----------------------------------------
1            0                 1
2            1                 2
3            1                 2
```

**Table 2**

```
KID ParentID    KLevel      InfoDate
------------------------------------------------------------    
2   1            2          2015-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

I want insert all record from first table to second table that not exist in second table with condition `InfoDate=2015-12-31 00:00:00.000`

**For example**, in this sample example records with `KID=1` and `KID=3` must be inserted into table 2.

I do:

```
insert into table2 (KID , ParentID , KLevel)
select KID , ParentID , KLevel from table1
where not EXISTS(
    SELECT KID , ParentID , KLevel FROM table2 WHERE InfoDate = '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000'
);
```

but `(0 row(s) affected)`

could you help me, please?

Comment: define 'not exists' is there a key between the tables that tells you a record doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHERE NOT EXISTS...` condition does not really make sense. Right now you're only checking, if there is no row with `InfoDate = '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000'`. Since there obviously is such a row, no records are affected.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO [table2] (
       [KID]
     , [ParentID]
     , [KLevel]) 
SELECT
      [KID]
    , [ParentID]
    , [KLevel]
FROM [table1]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        [KID]
        , [ParentID]
        , [KLevel]
    FROM [table2]
    WHERE [InfoDate] = '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000'
      AND [table1].[KID] = [table2].[KID]
      AND [table1].[ParentID] = [table2].[ParentID]
      AND [table1].[KLevel] = [table2].[KLevel])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use any key value get the not existing records.

```
insert into table2 (KID , ParentID , KLevel)
select KID , ParentID , KLevel from table1
where KID NOT IN (
    SELECT KID FROM table2 WHERE InfoDate = '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correlate the two queries as:

```
insert into table2 (KID , ParentID , KLevel)
select t1.KID , t1.ParentID , t1.KLevel 
from table1 t1
where not EXISTS(
SELECT * 
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t2.KID = t1.KID AND t2.ParentID = t1.ParentID AND t2.KLevel = t1.KLevel
AND t2.InfoDate = '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If KID is unique in table...

insert into table2 (KID , ParentID , KLevel)
select KID , ParentID , KLevel from table1
where table1.KID not in (
    SELECT distinct KID FROM table2 WHERE InfoDate = '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000');